# Cannot login as admin after fresh ApacheDS instal

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I have downloaded the newest version of ApacheDS for Windows (2.0.0-M23).

After the installation on Windows7 Pro, with Java 1.8 u101 64 bit
which passed without any errors I tried to make a new connection from Eclipse, LDAP perspective from Apache DS Studio plugin, but cannot login as uid=admin,ou=system with a default password (secret), which should work for initial login.
I am using default localhost with port 389.

I get the error:
The authentication failed
- Cannot connect to the server: Connection refused: no further information
- No connection

I tried to point for Java1.7 at the installation with the same result.
Also tried to login from JXplorer.

Would you have any hints?

Comment: same issue faced ..default "secret" password won't work

Answer (score 1):

ApacheDS uses port 10389 right out of the box.
You can always make sure using the netstat tool.
You can change the port number from Apache Directory Studio using "Open Configuration" from the connection menu.

Comment: yep, changing port from 389 (default in the studio connection dialog ) to 10389 worked for me.  Cheers.